# Pass projection fields dynamically using another placeholder

Tags: mongodb, projection

I am trying to find out can I pass the projection fields for the Repository Query(MongoDB). we can do for the criteria section by using the placeholders, but the same is not working for the fields.

```
@Query(value="{ 'name' : ?0 }", fields="{ 'searchItems.id':1, 'searchItems.name':1, 'searchItems.address.zipcode':1}")
public List<SearchItems> findByName(String name);
```

Here I am trying to search records by name, where am projecting required fields. Now I need to pass the projection fields dynamically.

I tried like have an another placeholder; but it is failing.

```
@Query(value="{ 'name' : ?0 }", fields="{ ?1 }")
public List<SearchItems> findByName(String name, String prjFields);
```

Comment: "but it is failing." doesn't do what you expect it to do or throw an error?

Comment: Yes. its unable to process the query. Throwing exception form the Spring AOP framework.